# The proof of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I want to know whether my proof is correct.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, then for any $x\in [0,1]$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U_x =\{y: |x-y|<\varepsilon$ of $x$ so that $U_x \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset$. Further, the collection $\{U_x: x \in [0,1]\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there is finite subset $D$ of $[0,1]$ such that $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{x\in D} U_{x}$. So, we have $[0,1] \cap\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in D} U_{x}$. Therefore, we deduce that $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is totally bounded.

Note: a metric space $(X,d)$ is called totally bounded if for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a finite set $A\subseteq X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{x\in A}B_d(x, \varepsilon)$.

Comment: Concerning the correctness, one would need to know the definition of totally bounded in use. There are different but equivalent definitions, and the correctness depends on which definition is used.

Answer (score 1):

No you have several errors. First

> Since $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, then for any $x\in[0,1]$, there exists an
>   open neighbourhood $U_x=\{y:|x−y|<\epsilon\}$ of $x$ so that $U_x\cap \mathbb{Q}Q\not=\not 0$.

doesn't really make sense. What density implies is that for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ $B_d(x,\epsilon)\cap \left(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\right) \not= \not0$. You should use that to show that 
$$
[0,1]\subset \bigcup_{x\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}} B_d(x,\epsilon).
$$
And then use that $[0,1]$ is compact as you did and make the conclusion.